# get network error when trying to upload tests into testrail by testrail cli tool

Tags: command-line-interface, testrail

I experience a strange problem. Maybe someone has experienced the same and found solution. When I try to upload my testrail tests in xml file format to Testrail by the testrail cli tool I got this error saying upload failed due to network error and that I need to make sure I have a valid network connection. I do have a valid network connection so I can't see the problem, so my only guess is maybe it is because of the thing that I'm using VPN. If it is the problem is there a way to get rid of the error by still using VPN?

[errormfrom terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnc6J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Running into this as well. Not using a VPN and the whole connection is local, so it looks like VPN might not play a role.

Extra details: I started working with the TRcli upload yesterday. On that day I did get errors but iirc those involved the xml file itself (parse_junit section of the code). I expect that point to have been beyond the moment where this network error is popping up today. I can be wrong though, since nothing in the code changed between yesterday and today.

**Update 1:** I am searching through the plugin to understand where the fault is called.
In the faultmapping section, the logline exists as:

```
 connection_error="Upload to TestRail failed due to a network error. Please make sure you have a "
    "valid network connection then try again."
```

connection_error is called in trcli\api\api_client.py

**Update 2:**
Turning on verbose gives more details in my case of this problem.
I see multiple retries on https://[...]/index.php?/api/v2/get_projects
Then it resorts to the connection error.

Running that same endpoint through postman results in a success, so further investigation with the trcli scripts seems necessary.

**Update 3:**
After updating TRCLI and running insecure as test, the connection also established here. Connection error indicates an SSL error.

Two courses of actions are currently planned:

1. Verify Testrail certificate so the --insecure command is no longer necessary.
2. Update Testrail to latest version (for an api error that followed up)

Comment: Update: I found out that if I add --insecure tag when running, it works without problem, maybe not the the best solution but at least it works :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at Railflow CLI tool (https://railflow.io) which is commercial tool but it has some free features for JUnit reports uploading. Disclaimer: I'm  developing Railflow

Comment: Oof, running insecure is a solution... but sending data over http instead of https is not an option I want to pursue. I'll search some more.

Comment: @Noxfulgens totally understand. I think I'll also drop it as the network issue is not the only issue I'm dealing with. Cli tool also needs an xml report in very specific format and as I'm using testcafe. it maens i have to make some plugin that can generate the xml report for me, extra work... I guess it is still easier for me to just upload the tests by directly using testrail API

Comment: That sounds like a good weighing of priorities. Still, if I find out the issue I'll add it to the update in case someone else runs into it.  Maybe at some point Gurock updates the cli to accept different report formats.